# unable to set npm terminal into VS code / windows

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

I want to install react, so I searched and I see I must download npm first
so I went to download npm, and I saw I must download node and set it in VS code terminal

I download `nodejs.zip` and but it in this path `C:\node\node.exe`
after this I went to cmd and wrote `node -v`, replied:

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

then I went to the control panel and wrote the path to the system vars
the same thing happens

I searched in StackOverflow and I found I most write **`SET PATH=C:\node\node.exe;%PATH%`** in cmd
it worked but not for a while, after restarting the PC the error still in my face

then I added node path to settings.json file like this

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    .
    .
    .
    "Node Js": {
        "path": "C:\\node\\node.exe"
    }
},
```

and make it default

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Node Js",
```

and finally, now I can run node in VS code "good rhythm"

but...
when I write `node -v` in node terminal replies :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: node is not defined

and when `npm init react-app myApp`:

> npm should be run outside of the Node.js REPL, in your normal shell.
> (Press Ctrl+D to exit.)

and on `npx create-react-app hi` :

> npx create-react-app hi
>
> ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ //pointing on `create`
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I only want to run this `npm init react-app myApp` or `npm init react-app myApp` command
IDC for node or anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try downloading `node.msi` (**setup file**) from [this link](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `SET PATH`, it sets the variable for the session, but if you want it to be permanent, put the path into the global PATH variable. See [this link](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/) on how to do it. In short, setting the variable in the command prompt lets you use the variable in the current command prompt session, and gets unset (or in this case, set back to the default) when you close the command prompt. Windows has a handful of environment variables that you can set which will be loaded automatically when you launch the command prompt, which `Path` is one of them. Alternatively, you can also do what you said and use the `.msi` file which does the job for you.